# How add new method in response and request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, prototypal-inheritance

I want to add new method in response and request of node.js.

How i can do it more efficiently?

I can't understand how this is done in express.js

Answer (score 8):

Being JavaScript, there are numerous ways to do this. The pattern that seems most reasonable to me for express is to add the function to each request instance in an early middleware:

```
//just an example
function getBrowser() {
    return this.get('User-Agent'); 
}

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.getBrowser = getBrowser;
  next();
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    //you can call req.getBrowser() here
});
```

In express.js, this is done by adding additional function to the prototype of http.IncomingMessage.

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/5638a4fc624510ad0be27ca2c2a02fcf89c1d334/lib/request.js#L18

This is sometimes called "monkey patching" or "freedom patching". Opinions vary on whether this is fantastic or terrible. My approach above is more prudent and less likely to cause intended interference with other code running inside your node.js process. To add your own:

```
var http = require('http');
http.IncomingMessage.prototype.getBrowser = getBrowser; //your custom method
```

Comment: I'm interested how this is done in express.js. How have been made custom request and response of express.js that passed in callback function in example 
`app.get('/', function (req, res) {

});`

Comment: Yes, my answer is for express. Your question is about to be closed for lack of sample code and explaining what you have tried.

Comment: I try to understand how this is done in express.js and i not found inside it same way. I think that it is done differently. I found in express.js next line `var req = exports = module.exports = {
  __proto__: http.IncomingMessage.prototype
};`. I think here happens inheritance of base functionality of request and after added custom method. I wanna know what happens next.

Comment: Explanation of how express does this added.

Comment: How to ensure that this function is not overloading express functions?

Comment: @AliSherafat You could check for a property with the name you intend to use with `typeof req.myNewMethod === 'undefined'` and abort if something is already defined there. That would handle express as well as any plugins or other code running in your process.

Answer (score 0):

Add methods to express.response object:

```
const express = require('express');
express.response.getName = () => { return 'Alice' };
```

Comment: This method is also suggested by express docs: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/overriding-express-api.html