# new middleware in express 3 fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is the middleware

```
app.use(function (req, res, next){

    res.locals.appdata      = appdata;
    res.locals.errorMessage = "";
    res.locals.information  = {};
    res.errorFromServer     = function (req, res){

        var mensaje = res.locals.errorMessage;

        res.status(500);
        res.locals.errorMessage = "";

        return res.render('error/500',{errorMessage: mensaje || ""});
    }

    next();
});
```

I'm trying to set a function in response object like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816685/how-add-new-method-in-response-and-request)

I'm getting this error

```
TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'errorFromServer'
```

Why my code is not working?

Comment: Where are you trying to use `res.errorFromServer()`? Is this middleware being `use`d before `app.use(app.router)` or the first route (`app.get()`, etc.)?

Comment: used after app.use(app.router

Comment: Order does matter with middleware. If `app.router` is first, then `errorFromServer` won't yet be defined for any of your routes.

Comment: i change the order and it worksso for every request the middleware re-define the function errorFromServer?, i have to put routes at last?

Comment: Not necessarily last. Just after this custom middleware. And, yes, it'll currently redefine `errorFromServer` for each `req` and `res`. But, that has more to do with scope, with it being defined inside another `function`, than to do with middleware specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is, You have used `res` object and returned a response using `return res.render(..)`. After that what is the use of `next()`?

And on top of that you are adding a function (not a value) to `res` object(answer which you referred uses `req` object and called a function and it has returned a value and it gets assigned to `req` object).

```
//Example
function getBrowser() {
    return this.get('User-Agent'); //This returns the value.
}

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.getBrowser = getBrowser; // You are assigning a value not a function itself.
  next();
});
```